# Angular 4 async await uncaught exception in promise

Tags: angular

I am always getting an error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): e: {"headers":{"normalize
>   dNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"

code is: (updated)

```
async verify() {
  let schema = {"token": localStorage.getItem('id_token')};
  let response: any = await this.http.post('/api-token-verify/', schema).toPromise();
  return response;
}

public async tokenAliveState() {
  console.log("1");
  let stuff = await this.verify();
  console.log("2");

  console.log("Returning from tokenAliveState");
  return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
}
```

All I want to do is make a post and wait for the response before moving on.  The response is plain JSON.

Angular core 4.

Any ideas?  Any more info needed?

Does anyone have a working example of a simple function to wait on an http response before continuing execution? All the example I found online show similar to this but no matter what I do I get the uncaught exception.

Comment: You're not doing the request as the API is expecting it. It's just that. That's what **`400`** means.

Comment: Is the url `/api-token-verify/` correct? does `schema` contain the proper data? Just saying... some questions to point you in the right direction...

Comment: You awaiting function inside other no-asynchronus function?

Answer (score 1):

You should always wrap an await call in a try catch block and then handle it accordingly.

```
try {
    let response: any = await this.http.post('/api-token-verify/', schema).toPromise();
} catch (err) {
    // Handle the 400 http code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"stuff" is a promise. You need to .then() and .catch() the response/errors from the async call. Basically, your http call didn't go through and you did not catch the error returned from the promise.

```
stuff
  .then(() => {})
  .catch((error) => {})
```

should make your error go away.

Comment: BTW, `tokenAliveState` must be `sync` too

Comment: Tried this. Same error as original.  400 is ok from that api, I just don't want it to crash.  That is the built in django rest framework jwt verify api. It returns 400 if the token is bad and 200 if it is good

Comment: @MichaelaErvin If you catch your errors, it won't crash or say "uncaught in promise"